# Cross-platform RPC with large messages

Tags: c++, .net, cross-platform, protocol-buffers, rpc

I have an application where I need to issue commands from a .NET application running on Windows to a C++ application running on Linux over a dedicated Ethernet connection between the two machines.

Rather than rolling my own protocol, I'd prefer to use some standard form of RPC.  Previously I've used XML RPC for cross-platform applications, but these particular commands need to contain a lot of numeric data (several thousand double floating-point values per command), with commands sent frequently, so I'm thinking some sort of binary serialization is a better fit.  As such, I've started looking into Protocol Buffers.

So, a few questions:

1. I know that Protocol Buffers define a serialization format, but is there any accepted industry standard for how to perform cross-platform RPC using them?
2. Are Protocol Buffers well-suited to representing nested data structures with variable-sized arrays?  The number of points per command is variable and the most natural representation of part of the data is an array of structures that each contain an array of points.  All of these arrays will have variable sizes for any given command.
3. Are there any gotchas you've run into when using Protocol Buffers for cross-platform communication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, there is no generally accepted standard. Some libraries come with their own RPC implementations, but none of them seems to be particularly popular. (Edit: As of 2019, [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) has become quite popular.)
2. Pretty good in my opinion. Some libraries even allow for lazy decoding, so that you do not need to decode all of the nested structures if you only need a part of the data.
3. In addition to the RPC format not being defined, the framing of the messages is not defined. So you have to do some custom method such as adding a length field in the beginning. Another undefined part is how to identify the type of the message being transmitted. Make sure to clearly define these for your own project.